# How to setup AWS Cognito natively for social login with swift without using AmplifyCLI?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, amazon-cognito, google-signin

In our app, we are using AWSCognitoIdentityProvider natively for Cognito Authentication. We are able to successfully sign-up, sign-in, reset password, etc. but I am struggling to find a complete example to help me setup authentication via social providers (e.g. facebook, google). Within my Cognito, I have successfully connected google with my userpool and using a web URL, I am able to create a cognito 'sub' for them successfully but hoping I can get some help with respect to setting it up within Swift.

Within my Cognito, I have successfully connected google with my userpool and using a web URL, I am able to create a cognito 'sub' for them successfully but hoping I can get some help with respect to setting it up within Swift.

This is from my AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            // setup logging
            AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .verbose
            AWSDDLog.add(AWSDDTTYLogger.sharedInstance)

            // setup cognito config
            self.cognitoConfig = CognitoConfig()

            // setup cognito
            setupCognitoUserPool()

            return true
    }

    func setupCognitoUserPool() {
        let clientId:String = self.cognitoConfig!.getClientId()
        let poolId:String = self.cognitoConfig!.getPoolId()
        let clientSecret:String = self.cognitoConfig!.getClientSecret()
        let region:AWSRegionType = self.cognitoConfig!.getRegion()

        let serviceConfiguration:AWSServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: region, credentialsProvider: nil)
        let cognitoConfiguration:AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: clientSecret, poolId: poolId)
        AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: cognitoConfiguration, forKey: userPoolID)
        let pool:AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool = AppDelegate.defaultUserPool()
        pool.delegate = self 
    }
```

Below is the code I have so far for email-based authentication and I am looking for something similar for FB/Google:

```
@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            let username:String = usernameInput?.text ?? "No username found"
            let password:String = passwordInput?.text ?? "No password found"

            // some code to check if username/password fields are empty. Throw error.

            user = AppDelegate.defaultUserPool().currentUser()

            self.user?.getSession(username, password: password, validationData: nil).continueWith {(task) -> AnyObject? in
                DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: {
                    let userSessionStatus = self.user?.isSignedIn

                    if userSessionStatus == true {
                            // take the user to welcome screen view controller
                    } else {
                            // Login failed. Ask the user to retry
                    }

                })
                return nil
            }
        }
```

Comment: Any help? Would love to get this sorted out if others were able to solve this problem. My research have found these SO questions but no clear answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807894/swift-aws-cognito-facebook-login
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491909/integrating-congnito-user-pools-with-amazon-cognito-identity